# Getting a cube with X volume in scilab or MATLAB?

Tags: scilab

I have a scilab program for averaging a 3D matrix and it works ok.However, instead of having the average just be a set value.I want it to be a certain sum of mass(sum(n*n*n).

```
K = 100
N = 5
A = 1 

mid = floor(N/2) 

volume = rand(K, K, K)

cubeCount = floor( K / N )

for x=0:cubeCount­1
    for y=0:cubeCount­1
        for z=0:cubeCount­1 

            // Get a cube of NxNxN size  
            cube = 20;


            //Calculate the average value of the voxels in the cube
            avg = sum( cube ) / (N * N * N);

             // Assign it to the center voxel
            volume( N*x+mid+1, N*y+mid+1, N*z+mid+1 ) = avg

        end
     end
 end 

disp( volume )
```

If anyone has a simple solution to this, please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have just about said it your self. All you would need to do would be change cube to equal.

```
cube = while sum(A * A * A) < 10,

A=A+1;
```

This will give you the correct sum of mass of the voxels.

Comment: But will this make it go out in all directions.

Comment: Not sure what you mean